# When I use the package AcademicTwitterR and function 'get_all_tweets' it seems to return the shortened version of the original tweet

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to pull tweets that use a particular term for topic analyses.

I am able to successfully extract tweets using the R package AcademicTwitterR with the function `get_all_tweets`. However, the text/tweets seem to be shortened from the original.

For example a tweet text might look like this:

> "Not exactly, although invasive species can become a problem as well
> (talk to Australians about rabbits for..."

I would like to pull the whole tweet.

Example code I used:

```
df <- get_all_tweets(query = "invasive species", start_tweets = "2006-10-01T00:00:00Z",end_tweets = "2021-10-01T00:00:00Z")
```

Comment: Is this the case for all Tweets, or only for retweets?

Comment: Ah yes, it does seem that it may just be retweets (text that starts with RT). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Christopher Barrie, who made the package, replied. The code does pull all the tweets but the way I was binding the tweet rows was the problem.

An alternative option for binding the rows which converts JSON files to various data frame formats:

The “vanilla” format. direct output from jsonlite::read_json. It can display columns such as text just fine.

```
bind_tweets(data_path = "tweetdata") %>% as_tibble
```

The “raw” format. a list of data frames containing all of the data extracted in the API call.

```
bind_tweets(data_path = "tweetdata", output_format = "raw") %>% names
```

The “tidy” format.

```
bind_tweets(data_path = "tweetdata", output_format = "tidy")
```

More information here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/academictwitteR/vignettes/academictwitteR-tidy.html

Comment: Do not leave your answer in a link. Keep the link for reference, but explain in your post what worked for you. This approach avoids the problem of dead links in the future. ;-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).